# Can a real life person be named after a fictional character?

Tags: united-states, name

Can a person from real life have its legal name identical of that of a fictional character? E.g if a newly born person is named "Sorla Khan" or "Mogul Khan" (names from the Dota universe) or "Galadriel" from The Lord of the Rings.

Comment: There are a huge number of Clark Kent's in the USA.

Comment: @gnasher One of the inspirations for my own son's first name is Clark Kent. My daughter's first name is also after a fictional character.

Comment: People have even changed their names...Optimus Prime deployed to Iraq in 2003.  https://www.tribemagazine.com/board/threads/optimus-prime-goes-to-iraq.34585/

Comment: I suspect that, as is often the case, there's only an issue if they try to use their name in a way that might be confused as infringing on a trademark, e.g. if you're named Optimus Prime, there probably isn't an issue with operating Optimus Prime's Auto Repair, but Hasbro will probably start sending notices if you operate as Optimus Prime Transforming Robots.